# Does docker stack deploy work with local images

Tags: docker

I'm trying to use docker stack deploy to deploy a local node app. I'm having a terrible time getting a good workflow.

I'm confused with the stack deploy and relationship to docker hub. I'm happy to have to build the image locally, but pushing it is a problem because my network is so slow and the image is 169MB.

My question is, if I just build the image locally, should it then be deployed by the docker stack deploy? or do I always have to publish the new image to docker hub? n.b It's published to a private repository at the moment.

**Why I'm asking?**
I tried doing a local `docker build -t myname/myimage:latest`, then redeploy with docker stack deploy with `docker-compose.yml` that references image `myname/myimage:latest` - but another image keeps reappearing from 24 hours ago even if I removed it locally using `docker rmi` (again and again). And then the service fails to start with errors that should be resolved in the new build.

I can only think that the container deployed by stack deploy is based on the one that's published in docker hub rather than the local image. Certainly the size of the image that keeps appearing in the `docker images` matches the old image that's currently in docker hub, rather than the new one.

Perhaps I'm doing something wrong or misunderstanding how the stack deploy works?

Comment: I guess the docker deploy command just works for images on repository, and if you want to run a local image you have to run docker-compose up, it´s just a guess, because I am having the same problem and that´s how is working for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try building your local image this way:

> docker build -t myimage .

and refer it as "myimage:latest" in your compose file, if you want to use the local image.

If you want to push this to the hub then tag it first

> docker tag id_of_myimage my_dockerhub_username/myimage:latest

and then push it.

> docker push my_dockerhub_username/myimage:latest

Comment: It works for new build but if I update the stack, I get this error: `unable to pin image rsc:latest to digest: errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
unauthorized: authentication required` - I tried running `--with-registry-auth` but didn't help in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In this workflow I would suggest running the docker-registry container locally in another Stack and then tagging and pushing your images to that "host" so that you can pull them from there when building your other stacks.

```
docker build -t my.docker.registry:5000/myimage:latest -t my.docker.registry:5000/myimage:specificversion .
```

Then `docker push my.docker.registry:5000/myimage` which will put it on your local registry.

After that you should be able to pull from it for your stacks and push a new version and tag it as latest whenever you change the contents of the container.

Outlined with an alternate example, https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-swarm-mode-and-local-images/22894/3

Answer (score 0):

There are a few bugs in Docker regarding this

- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31357
- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30951

I ended up [writing a script](https://gist.github.com/trajano/82982c229948df445ada518d7c6273df) to do what I need for myself.  This script is intended for a local single-node swarm (which is what I have in development)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $stack_name = shift;
open(TASKS, qq#docker stack ps --format "{{.ID}} {{.Image}}" --no-trunc $stack_name|#) || die $!;
my %tasks;
while (<TASKS>) {
    my ($id, $image) = m/^([^\s]+?)\s(.*)$/;
    $tasks{$id} = $image;
}
close(TASKS);

my %needs_update; 
for my $task_id (keys %tasks) {
    open(CONTAINER, qq#docker ps --filter "name=.*$task_id" --no-trunc --format '{{.Image}} {{.ID}}'|#) || die $!;
    $_ = <CONTAINER>;
    my ($image, $container_id) = m/^([^\s]+?)\s(.*)$/;
    close(CONTAINER);

    if ($image && $image ne $tasks{$task_id}) {
        open(CONTAINERINSPECT, q#docker inspect --format '{{ index .Config.Labels "com.docker.swarm.service.name" }}' # . $container_id . "|") || die $!;
        $_ = <CONTAINERINSPECT>;
        chomp;
        $needs_update{$_} = $tasks{$task_id};
        close(CONTAINERINSPECT);
    }
    
}
for(keys %needs_update){
    open(UPDATE, "docker service update -d --no-resolve-image --force --image $needs_update{$_} $_ |") || die $!;
    print <UPDATE>;
    close(UPDATE);
}
```